# convert string to float with input file

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, input, floating-point

```
# This program asks for an input and output file, and uses mult. and add.
# to combine files

def main():
    print("This program creates a file of numbers from a")
    print("file of numbers.")

    infileName = input("What file are the numbers in? ")
    outfileName = input("What file should the numbers go in? ")

    infile = open(infileName, 'r')
    outfile = open(outfileName, 'w')

    for line in infile:
        nums = line.split()
        nums = float()
        first = nums[0]
        second = nums[-1]
        newfirst = (first + second)
        newsecond = (first * second)
        print(newfirst, newsecond, file=outfile)
        
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()

    print("Numbers have been written to", outfileName)

main()
```

the input txt file looks like this:

4.5 16.8
15 25
150 220.4
5.8 90
-1 -2
6.8 -2.3

this is what i have so far, I know everything is right other than the part where I split the input file. I just want to know how to convert the numbers in the input file to floats so i can add them and multiply them

Comment: Converting input to a float is a basic tutorial item.  We expect you to look up such things before posting here.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You've overwritten ```nums``` when you put ```nums = float()```.   you could just combine the two lines into ```nums = [float(x) for x in line.split()]```

Comment: What do you expect `nums = float()` to accomplish and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace this:

```
        nums = line.split()
        nums = float()
        first = nums[0]
        second = nums[-1]
```

with this:

```
        nums = line.split()
        first = float(nums[0])
        second = float(nums[-1])
```

or this:

```
        nums = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
        first = nums[0]
        second = nums[-1]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Sorry for the dumb question...still learning.

Comment: @fizzy That's alright! Everyone was "still learning" at some point!